# High voltage step up power module

Tags: electromagnetism, high-voltage, generator, tesla-coil

I have bought the stuff in the image below from eBay in order to generate an electrostatic field.

[image: high voltage steop up power module]
But the spec of the item is, well ..., written in chineese with some english flavor.
I have tried to obtain informations from the seller and sellers of similar item, but they know nothing. 
My question is addressed to persons that have bought the same item, know it, or are able to understand the spec.

Is the device suitable to be connected a long time without being discharged, or will it burn in this case ?

I've tried the device and it chirps as soon as it is connected, is it normal ?

thx.

Comment: Look at the distance between that devices terminals. Then look up what voltage is needed to spark over that gap. Then slowly toss that "thing" into the trash and start reading about how high voltage generation works for x00kV levels.

Comment: Of course, it is evident that these "things" must be used with great care. This item works on the principle of Testla's coil high voltage generation.

Comment: and that makes it magically not spark over its terminals when it reaches 400kV?

Comment: No it doesn't if the extremities of the wires are sufficiently distant one to the other. The sparking effect is due to air ionization that becomes conductible in an avalanche effect; since the wires are insulated, the ions cannot reach the copper inner wires, no avalanche effect and no spark is produced between the wires, unless, of course, the extremities of the wires that are not insulated are sufficiently close one to the other.

Comment: So you get 150mm sparks and their wires are insulated with the latest high end insulator so that they can widthstand it? impressive.

Comment: According to my tries, I get only 4-5 cm sparks, so, this is probably much less than 400KV. I have also tried to stick the two wires (far from their extremities) to see if the insulator melts, and it does not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41858/discussion-between-miketex-and-plasmahh).

Comment: @PlasmaHH You missed the impotant detail in the datasheet that reveals its capabilities: "This module is a small production with high-pressure science inverter transformer ":)

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You don't know what this thing does exactly or how to use it, but you bought it anyway?  And *now* you're trying to figure out its specs?  Perhaps I can interest you in a bridge in New York I'm trying to sell.

Comment: My aim is to generate an electrostatic field sufficiently strong to be suitable for my experiments. All what I need is a stable source of high voltage without ripple. These device cost about 1$, so ... I  tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these devices seem to be popular on Ebay and other shops, I believe that some persons may be interested to find the answer to my questions above and some other informations:

First the answer to my questions:

1. No, these devices are not suitable to be connected a long time: they need to be discharged in some load, and even so, they cannot resist a long time. In fact, they are at best suitable to realize some sparking experiences. I bought two such items of different kind, a small one that ridiculously claimed 400kV voltage (the one in the image above), and a second one, bigger, with voltage tuning, that claimed 12000V. The small one burnt after some 50 tries of less than 1min, mostly 10-20s each. The bigger one burnt even faster. These device MUST discharge into some load otherwise they burn quickly.
2. Apparently, the chirping is due to small sparks caused by some current flowing between the terminals and the rest of the world (not between them).

I've pulverised the two items to see how they are made; here are the pictures of what I found inside (small item in first position). 
[image: The small item - 400KV (:-))]
[image: The second item - 0-12000V :-) too]

3. Even so, I found these (very cheap) items useful for a first contact with high voltage and high impedance (they are probably *less* lethal than more serious devices). I've learnt a lot from experiences performed with them and from my tries to measure their output voltage (unfortunately, they burnt just before I was able to perform the measurements). Also, I've learnt some artefacts that you'll never see in low voltage: for example, I discovered that a 30cm piece of dry sandwich wood conducts current sufficiently well to feel a very disagreeable sensation.